# org-refile and separator lines

Tags: org-mode, org-refile

To improve readability I keep some headlines separated by blank lines:

```
* headline 1
* headline 2

* headline 3
```

While refiling to a headline immediately above a blank line using `org-refile` the refiled headline is placed below the blank line:

```
* headline 1
* headline 2

    * refiled headline
* headline 3
```

My understanding is that these blank lines are technically children of the parent headlines but that I'm able to get them to display regardless of the folded state of the parent headline by assigning a value to `org-cycle-separator-lines`. Is there any similar variable I can assign a value to in order to adjust the behavior of `org-refile` so that the refiled headline is placed above the blank line?

```
* headline 1
* headline 2
    * refiled headline

* headline 3
```

EDIT

In my config file I've got `org-cycle-separator-lines -1` while `org-refile-targets` is set on a per file basis - anywhere from 3-9.

Comment: What is the value of `org-cycle-separator-lines` in your config? Ditto for the value of `org-refile-targets`. Please update your question with the additional information.

Comment: I don't see any options to do what you want and some naive attempts on my part lead me to believe that  it's not possible without some significant effort on your part. Depending on how exactly you want to refile, you might be able to use the `RFLOC` argument of `org-refile` to specify *exactly* where to refile an item, but IMO it's not worth it, although YMMV. One question: what should happen if you refile two items? In what order do you expect them to be refiled under `headline 2`? For more info on RFLOC, search this site for `[org]RFLOC`.

Comment: This is what I'd been thinking - unless there's a variable similar to `org-cycle-separator-lines`I'd missed, I'm asking the impossible. I'd tend to agree with you that using `RFLOC` seems to be a bit more involved than what I was looking for.

  If I were to file two items I'd expect them to be filed under `headline 2` in the order added. After thinking about the reason behind your question I realized I could use `org-refile-reverse` if the order doesn't matter, which is actually a pretty clever workaround.

Comment: Well, yes, but I'm not sure how `org-refile-reverse` interacts with RFLOC. I was more concerned with calculating the position: it would be simpler to add a new entry right after the headline; otherwise, you'd have to march through all the previously added (sub)headlines to calculate the position of the new one.